# Scatter-Gather: merge into one map

Tags: mule

I need to query several tables and at the end of the scatter-gather flow I want to have a payload of this form

```
{table_1: [ list of results ], table_2: [ list of results ]}
```

I tried this:

```
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
    <processor-chain>
        <db:select config-ref="dataSrouce" doc:name="Table 1">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[// my query
        </db:select>

        <set-payload value="#[['table_1': #[payload]]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </processor-chain>
    <processor-chain>
        <db:select config-ref="dataSrouce" doc:name="Table 2">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[// my query
        </db:select>

        <set-payload value="#[['table_2': #[payload]]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </processor-chain>
</scatter-gather>

<set-payload value="#[groovy:payload.inject([:]) {result, entry -&gt; result += entry; result}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

But getting an exception:

```
Exception was found for route(s): 1. Message payload is of type: CaseInsensitiveHashMap (org.mule.routing.CompositeRouting
Exception)
  org.mule.routing.CollectAllAggregationStrategy:51 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/routing/Comp
ositeRoutingException.html)
```

Comment: One of the routes has encountered an exception. Your expressions within the scatter gather look fine. So probably the db:select is throwing an error. Not the groovy one though. You need to fix the exception being thrown form scatter gather first.

Comment: I think your use case is considered within the ```custom-aggregation-strategy``` option. You can define your own class to aggregate the results in whatever way you want. Check out the examples here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/292d0938eaac5f63219e7c20f564a9bd66c2bed6/tests/integration/src/test/java/org/mule/test/routing/ScatterGatherRouterTestCase.java

Comment: @RyanCarter you're right, there was something wrong with the db:select. Now it's complaining about the groovy part. `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.plus() is applicable for argument types: 
(java.lang.String) values: [{table_1=[[]]}]`

Comment: This is interesting... using dynamic query works and the result is no longer a string

Answer (score 0):

In each branch of your Scatter-Gather place an ObjectToString and an ObjectToJSON Transformer.

Then after the Scatter-Gather place a SetPayload with the following value:

```
{
    "table_1": #[payload[0]],
    "table_2": #[payload[1]]
}
```

Example:

```
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
    <processor-chain>
        <flow-ref name="Subflow_1" doc:name="Subflow_1"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        </processor-chain>
    <processor-chain>
        <flow-ref name="Subflow_2" doc:name="Subflow_2"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </processor-chain>
</scatter-gather>

<set-payload value="{
    &quot;table_1&quot;: #[payload[0]], 
    &quot;table_2&quot;: #[payload[1]]}" 
    doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/json"/>
```